# How to deploy migrations to an Opswork server via AWS::SDK

Tags: ruby, deployment, amazon-web-services

I have a RubyScript using the aws-sdk gem to create a deployment on our Opswork Server.

```
client.create_deployment({
  stack_id: "xxx",
  app_id: "xxx",
  instance_ids: ["xxx"],
  command: {
    name: "deploy"
  },
  comment: "ci deployment"
 })
```

But I can't figure out, what the right arguments are to migrate the database.

I tried something like this without success.

```
command: {
  name: "deploy",
  args: {
    "migrate" => ["true"]
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Ok my attempt actually works.

Comment: This feature actually has the worst documentation in all AWS land. I also only figured this out by trial-and-error (and reverse-engineering the form params from the AWS console).

Answer (score 0):

Scripts in the `deploy` folder will run at the appropriate times. So if you want to do a migration after deployment, add the command to your `after_deploy.rb` file.